# Run PHPUnit without shell access to my php server

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, remote-access

I seem to remember three years ago or so - the last time I looked into PHP - that it was simple to run PHP Unit tests.

However now I am looking around and I cant find any simple solution. Everything I try has too many requirements, either:

- It requires shell access to the php server (to run from the command line)
- Or I can use Visual PHP Unit but then I have a whole set of other requirements ...

see:

- It requires Apache. (for .htaccess)
- It requires OVERRIDE ALL
- It requires PEAR
- It requires a database

Is there a simpler way to run PHP Unit tests? Something that would just require PHP scripts and a browser? or at the most composer?

Something that would work in the average limited bare bones low budget hosting environment?

Comment: I know that PHPStorm IDE offers a feature to run Unit-Tests on your server: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-phpunit-on-server.html - But for a distinct setup - like for testing - you always have some work. Alternatively if you've got SSH access to your host, you can also just run it in CLI. I normally won't call that too many requirements. But probably you're just a bit complaining because you don't get it to run? I can hardly imagine it was a better situation years ago. The alternative is to test in your dev environment.

Comment: You'd be surprised. PHPUnit used to include a pure php runner. Most of the hosting my students end up with, dont allow for any shell (or SSH) access, and therefore can not run Pear. So requiring either shell access or pear locks them totally out

Comment: I think there still is a webinterface for PHPUnit. And the testrunner itself still is in PHP. And instead of pear you can package phpunit with composer so you can configure the software on your system and then upload to the server. So the requirements you give seem a little bit misleading to me, even if the servers capabilities are limited, as long as you can upload files and the server exectutes PHP, there is nothing that prevents running the tests remotely I'd say. I'd say it would be a good task to get that to run for your students. A good excercise.

Comment: You didn't read my post.
PHPUnit would work fine because you can deploy it with composer, but there is NOT a php runner anymore. All the documentation says to use VisualPhP, but thats obviously not a real option for a large percent of PHP programmers out there.

Comment: You didn't read my comment, there is no such large percent of PHP programmers that need it hence the feature ain't there. Think about it. So you need to do it your own because of the localized use-case.

Comment: Is exec() enabled on the host?